# Randomly Shuffling 2 Arrays in Unison in C

Tags: c, arrays, random, shuffle

Say I have two arrays KEYS and VALS and I want to randomly shuffle them in unison (after the shuffling the key value pair matching should be preserved).

If I seed the random function with a static value and then call std::random_shuffle on KEYS and then VALS will both arrays be shuffled the same way?

Comment: Shuffle and array of indices, and then use that to reorder the two arrays

Comment: Why not shuffle a `boost::zip_iterator`?

Comment: If you use the same seed before each shuffle, then yes ... how could it be otherwise? But why are your keys and vals in different arrays? Put a key and val together in a struct.

Comment: Ah, well done to Jim for discerning the real problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will, but only if you shuffle the first, then seed the random number generator with the same value, then shuffle again. And you should be using the same shuffle function for both; it is dangerous to use different shufflers which may or may not call rand() a different number of times.
However, I recommend you associate the data in some way; you could implement a map or just put the data together in a struct. Keeping the arrays separate and trusting that your *random* function will shuffle them the exact same way is asking for trouble.